# Outlook 2010/2013 Set desktop alert for unread mail only

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have two mailboxes attached to Outlook 2010 on my work PC and Outlook 2013 on my personal laptop. For one of these mailboxes I don't wish to see desktop alerts so I have disabled them so that they only show for my main mailbox. This works fine and can be summarised with the following rule description:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
on this computer only
display a Desktop Alert
except through the whatever@hotmail.co.uk
```

However, if on an evening away from work I read my email on my laptop, when I arrive back at work the following day I will get an alert for every single email that my work Outlook hasn't seen before regardless of whether it is read or not.

Is there a way to configure my rule so I only see an alert for unread mail? I've looked through all the conditions offered by Outlook for rule conditions and I don't see a way.

Comment: you leave outlook running at work all night or shut it down? It might be checking every 10mins and downloading every email and creating the alert at that time, and not when you come in the following morning and sit down.

Comment: Nope, PC is shutdown at night when I leave - don't really want to change from this if possible.